# How to pass variables from while loop of PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, while-loop

please help me. 
windows.location is working, but $id & $waktu only get the last value.
not get from the selected. thanks alot.

While loop for :

```html
<?php
  $tampil=mysql_query
  ("SELECT * FROM ms_modul");
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tampil))
     {
       $id = $row['noid_modul'];
       $judul  = $row['judul_modul'];
       $waktu = $row['waktu'];
       $waktuMenit = $waktu/60; 
       echo $judul 
       echo $waktuMenit; echo " menit"; ?>

<input id="test" value="?module=quizcek&id=<?php echo $id ?>&waktu=<?php echo $waktu; ?>" >
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="sweet()" id="btnShowAlert">Mulai Quiz</button>

        <?php } ?>
```

javascript:

```html
<script>
  function sweet (){
  var ambil = document.getElementById('test').value;
  swal({
  title: 'Mulai mengerjakan quiz?',
  text: '',
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Ya',
  cancelButtonText: 'batal',
  confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success",
  cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger",
  buttonsStyling: false
  }).then(function() {                  

  window.location=ambil
  }, function(dismiss) {
   // dismiss can be 'overlay', 'cancel', 'close', 'esc', 'timer'                  
  })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: [Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: using PDO ?thanks for the answer

Comment: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), yes. You shouldn't use `mysql_connect` anymore.

Comment: ok i try, thanks alot.